# What would be the best layout to have a user enter their SSN in android?

Tags: android, authentication

Creating a new app for a company which will have a 3 digit company id, and a 9 digit SSN id. Would Edit Text fields be the best way to go?

Comment: The question wouldn't be considered a opinion but facts. A simple Yes or No question asking if EditText would be the way to go. Thanks Though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, EditText's are your best better for any keyboard centric data entry.  You can tell the keyboard what kind of data to expect and it will customize the keyboard for that kind of data using the `inputType` attribute.  If you are only expecting digits then

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/numberEntry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

This will tell the keyboard to display the number pad.  More options here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType and an explanation here https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html .   However specifying an inputType does not stop a user from entering non-numerics through a physical keyboard.  You need to validation afterwards.

You can limit the number of characters using

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

Answer (score 1):

An `EditText` should certainly work here, as @browep mentions. I will add, though, that you'll likely want to use the `textPassword` `android:inputType`. This will give your user a sense of security sense the entered characters are hidden from view. There are a few other things you can do to make sure your users are entering their SSN's correctly.

1. specify the `android:digits` attribute. For an ssn, it might be something like: "0123456789-". This attribute limits input to the characters you specify;
2. add a useful hint to tell your users the input you expect. For example, you can define a string resource `<string name="ssn_hint">555-55-5555</string>` and include it as a hint like so `android:hint="@string/ssn_hint";
3. as @browep states, use the `android:maxLength` attribute. I'd recommend a length of 11 characters, though, to accommodate the dashes: `android:maxLength="11"`;
4. use a text mask to automatically validate the input. Unfortunately, there are not any great libraries I've come across, but you might try https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText or https://github.com/reinaldoarrosi/MaskedEditText.

At the end of the day, you'll end up with an `EditText` looking like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ssn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="01234567890-"
    android:hint="@string/ssn_hint"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLength="11"/>
```